# How to record Reason5 output

Tags: audio-recording, reason

I have Reason5 + audioKontrol  soundcard +midi device+guitar(with guitarRig)
I want to record Reason output. Tried different DAWs with rewire.
The problem is I don't want rewire to control midi, transport or loop. I want it to record output audio only.
Is it possible? How? With which DAW?

Comment: I'm curious if you are asking for a specific use? Because Reason has a built-in export audio option.

Comment: @GuneyOzsan Me and the guitarist are playing simultaneously. I play a 4 bar loop adding/muting tracks. We can't stop the playback to edit. I wan't to record the entire session as it is.

Comment: So you are using Reason in loop mode, rather than the song mode. Is it right?

Comment: If this is the case I see no other option than using rewire and a DAW. Have you also tried Propellerhead's Record software?

Comment: @GuneyOzsan That is the problem. When I use reWire in also controls the loop, and I don't want this to happen

Comment: I edited my answer regarding the details. Unfortunately there isn't a clear solution that I can come up with. But you may get some ideas to work around the issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are two work arounds (rather than solutions) to do that.

- To use a second PC which records the line-out from Audio Kontrol (and MIDI signals if necessary). You will need another sound card with a line level input for low noise recording.

The next option needs you to spare two line-in's and two line-out's of Audio Kontrol. (This may not work for you since one of the two line-in channels of Audio Kontrol is used for guitar).

- Make a U-connection with two short 1/4" cables from two of your line-out's to two line-in's of your sound card. Be sure not to hit 0dB on Main Out and putting a limiter to 0dB may be safes.
- Find a DAW with ReWire support which also saves all takes recorded in loop mode into one single audio file (I know Nuendo 4 does this, there should also be others as well).
- Prepare a muted stereo channel in the DAW which records line-in's coming from U-connection. Be sure to mute this channel to prevent feedback loops. (Later the single audio file that contains this channel's loop takes will be the recording session output.)
- Run Reason as a slave of the DAW.
- Record your session in loop mode.
- The session will be ready recorded in one single audio file. Each DAW uses a different folder system for recorded files. You may need to look around a little to find that file.